# How to add a marker to OpenLayers map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to show OpenStreetMap in my web site using OpenLayers library. I want to add a marker but the marker does not show up on the map.

I had searched on Google, I had found one code as below my code.
There are much examples to add marker but it dominates for Google maps. I want to use open source map.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/ css/ol.css" type="text/css">
     <style>
       .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

///SHOW MAP
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([106.8478695, -6.1568562]),
          zoom: 17
        })
      });
///ADD MARKER
    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);

    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('marker.png', size, offset);
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(106.8478695,-6.1568562),icon));
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(106.8478695,-6.1568562),icon.clone()));

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

code snippet:

```js
///SHOW MAP
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([106.8478695, -6.1568562]),
    zoom: 17
  })
});
///ADD MARKER
var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
map.addLayer(markers);

var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21, 25);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w / 2), -size.h);
var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('marker.png', size, offset);
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(106.8478695, -6.1568562), icon));
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(106.8478695, -6.1568562), icon.clone()));
```

```css
.map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/ css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<title>OpenLayers example</title>
<h2>My Map</h2>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

I expect the marker show up on the map, but I don't see the  marker.

Answer (score 12):

You are using OpenLayers 2 code to add a marker to an OpenLayers 5 map.

The equivalent code for OpenLayers 3/4/5 is

```js
    var markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector(),
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 1],
          src: 'marker.png'
        })
      })
    });
    map.addLayer(markers);
    
    var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([106.8478695, -6.1568562])));
    markers.getSource().addFeature(marker);
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned the version of `OpenLayers` you are using. So giving an example that works on `OpenLayers v3`

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([39.8262, 21.4225]),
    zoom: 15
  })
});

var markerGeometry = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([39.8262, 21.4225], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:4326'));
var markerFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: markerGeometry
});

var markerStyle = new ol.style.Icon(({
    src: 'https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v3.20.1/examples/resources/logo-70x70.png'
}));

markerFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: markerStyle,
}));

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [markerFeature]
});

var markerLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: "RoutePoint",
    visible: true,
    source: vectorSource
});

map.addLayer(markerLayer);
```

```css
.map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/ css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<title>OpenLayers example</title>
<h2>Sample Map</h2>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```